# Magento 2.1.7 Change Shipping Method Title method.method_title USPS Pirority Mail Day 1

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I would like to change the shipping method title from
"Priority Mail 1-Day" to "Priority Mail"

how do I target this cleanly?

```
 <td class="col col-method" data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

 <td class="col col-carrier" data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
</tr>
```

This is Magento 2 and this data is displayed after a click event on a radio button. I'm thinking I might be able to do this a dirty way and use javascript to overwrite the string value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formA input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure that is the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for the `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method` class, like the following:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

class PluginName
{
    public function afterSetPrice($subject)
    {
        if ( $subject->getMethodTitle() === "Priority Mail 1-Day" ) {
            $subject->setMethodTitle("Priority Mail");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find a path \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method in my app directory. I'm using the Novetty Theme.

Comment: This didn't work I found the directory path in the vendor folder. made the changes and did a full cache.

Comment: The problem may be that the method title in the if statement isn't a match, copy exactly what appears in the checkout. I can confirm that this approach does work because I use it myself.

Comment: I am putting it in the  "class Method extends AbstractResult" class at the bottom and I checked the string it's a match completely. am I doing this wrong?

Comment: vendor > magento > module-quote > Model > Quote > Address > RateResult > method.php

Comment: You need to make a module, which is the basis of any modification to the magento system. There's plenty of tutorials around on how to do that. Once you have a module, you should learn about plugins, which is what the above code pertains to.