# How to create module for module_quote

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, shipping-methods

I am following this Aaron Allen's solution for my problem.

> [Magento 2.1.7 Change Shipping Method Title method.method_title USPS Pirority Mail Day 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195334/magento-2-1-7-change-shipping-method-title-method-method-title-usps-pirority-mai)

**He says "You need to make a module,** which is the basis of any modification to the Magento system. There's plenty of tutorials around on how to do that. Once you have a module, you should learn about plugins, which is what the above code pertains to".

So far I created my plugin in my vendor/magento/module_quote and its working fine but I don't know how to create a module for it and to do all these things there. Kindly guide me with some relevant example as I am a beginner to Magento 2.

Comment: Solved Problem. these video tutorials helped me in this regard
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGQcildhvCE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=682p52tFcmY

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Magento 2 Module consists the following parts:

- Module Structure
- Module Declaration
- Module Registration
- Check Module Status

**Module Structure**

In order to create a simple module in Magento 2, you first need to set up the structure of the module. Magento 2 module directory can be found in `Magento2Root/app/code`. The first folder is known as Namespace, and inside this folder, you have the module directory where you have to create further files and folders according to the Module's functionality. As an example, I'll be using **Cloudways** as namespace and **Mymodule** as the module name.

**Module Declaration**

Now, you have to declare the module by using the configuration file. As Magento 2 search for module's configuration in `Magento2Root/app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc`. So, create a configuration file `module.xml` in `Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/etc` directory and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Cloudways_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**Module Registration**

The module must be registered in the Magento 2 system by using Magento Component Registrar class. Now, create the file `registration.php` in the root directory of the module `Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/` and insert the following code into it:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Cloudways_Mymodule',
__DIR__
);
```

**Check Module Status**

After following the steps above, you have successfully created a simple Magento 2 module. Just enter the following Magento 2 CLI command to enable the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Cloudways_Mymodule
```

Now that you have enabled the module, you have to upgrade the system of Magento 2 by using this command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After successfully running both the commands, check the status of modules with this CLI command:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```